# Tuning gsutil cp flag options

Tags: google-cloud-platform, file-io, upload, gsutil, google-cloud-storage

Is there any advice on achieving optimal upload times for `gsutil cp` for files larger than 100GB? Currently, I am trying to tune the following flags:

```
    GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_component_size
    GsUtil:parallel_process_count
    GsUtil:parallel_thread_count
```

However, I don't have a very systematic way of doing this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What custom values to use depends on your network speed, latency, OS TCP/IP stack configuration, etc. Your question does not have those details. If you change the values and you do not understand them, you will most likely decrease performance. The operating system can also override custom settings in the TCP/IP stack.